# How to return from a php deferred promise

Tags: php, lumen

Not able to return value from a `deferred->promise()`. I have a method in my controller that is a deferred promise with a guzzle async call to a rest API that fetches data. When resolving the `deferred->promise()` in the controller method, the return does not send back the data. But I can see the data I need when I use `print_r`.

```php
class CharController extends BaseController {
    public function getCharacters() {
        $characterService = new CharacterService;

        $characterService->getCharacters()
            ->then(function($result) {
                print_r($result);
                return new Response(201, ['Content-type' => 'application/json'], $result);
            });
    }
}
-- In another file.--
public function getCharacters() {
        $deferred = new Deferred();
        $client = new Client();
        $promise = $client->getAsync("https://sample.com/api/getData");

        $promise
            ->then(function (ResponseInterface $res) use ($deferred) {
                $body = json_decode((string) $res->getBody(), true);
                $deferred->resolve($body);
            }, function (RequestException $e) use ($deferred) {
                echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
                $deferred->reject($e);
            });
        $response = $promise->wait();

        return $deferred->promise();
    }
```

I need `CharController@getCharacters()` to return the data from the api but i get no response. I can see the data from the `print_r()`.

Comment: I [think](https://github.com/guzzle/promises#synchronous-wait) `$promise->wait();` will force the promise to complete making this horrendously complicated code totally unnecessary...

Comment: If i dont have  the $promise->wait(), the api response isn't being fetched. Pardon my code. I am new to php. How do u suggest to refactor this?

Comment: Unless you need async HTTP just `$response = $client->get($url)` will put the JSON string in `$response`. Then you can `return json_decode((string) $res->getBody(), true);` and that's the end of `getCharacters`... two lines of code. In `CharController` do `$data = $service->getCharacters()` and bam, you have your data. This is not JavaScript, PHP is a simple language ...

Comment: ya that makes sense. I tried this and it worked fine. The app i am trying to build just makes calls to an API and fetches data. It doesn't have a database. So you suggest just using sync calls? And you are right, my thinking is coming more from my Js background and that is where i am mistaken.